# What do the commands on this cake do?

Tags: linux, bash

To celebrate my 3 month probation as a web developer concluding, I'm going to make a terminal cake for the office. In my research on the subject I came across this photo, and was wondering what the commands do?

[image: cake picture]

Comment: They're supposed to stop any `httpd` (web server) process on the machine. But the command is broken. :-\

Comment: Well, the values passed to `kill -9` will include more than just process ids, but unless some of them happen to be valid PIDs, it will just print a bunch of error messages and kill the processes anyway. (But on my system, where I run Apache, the web server processes are named `apache2`, not `httpd`.)

Comment: Thanks both, my curiosity has been sated! I guessed it might have been something along those lines.

Comment: Curious. The hostname is "sigint", but the signal is SIGKILL.

Comment: simple trick to eliminate grep -v grep ... use square brackets on one of the letters such as: `grep [h]ttpd` ... wouldn't want to miss a server running in ./bigreport/www

Comment: Or do it properly and use `pgrep`/`pkill`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That pipeline tries to stop all of the Apache processes on the system, in a rather heavy-handed [Rube Goldbergian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rube_Goldberg_machine) fashion.

The pipeline:

1. **Gets a list of all processes on the system.** (`ps axww`)

   This method is an overreach, providing more data than is actually necessary to achieve the desired end, which will cause problems later.
2. **Looks for lines containing `httpd`**, which is a common process name for the Apache web server. It could match other things accidentally, but on a machine that's supposed to just be a web server, it's *fairly* safe.

   You get lines like this out of this stage:

   ```
   17652 ?        Ss     0:00 /usr/bin/httpd -blah -args
   ```

   The pipeline would match a `vi /etc/httpd/conf.d/mime.conf` command, too.
3. **Filters out lines containing `grep`** (`grep -v grep`) because the first `grep` will also find *itself*:

   ```
   24180 pts/0    R+     0:00 grep httpd
   ```

   If you don't filter this line out, you risk killing off the first `grep` instance before the pipeline finishes, thereby breaking the pipeline. `ps` on Linux sorts its output by PID by default, so since [PIDs wrap around](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11323410/linux-pid-recycling), `grep` could appear before `httpd`, causing the cake command to actually have no effect at all.
4. **Uses [`xargs`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xargs) to run `kill -9`** on every line found.

   That is, it builds commands like this and runs them:

   ```
   kill -9 17652 ?        Ss     0:00 /usr/bin/httpd -blah -args
   ```

   This may or may not do what you want. It *can sometimes* work because the process ID (PID) is the first thing on the line when you run `ps` with the `axww` flags. (There are other ways to run `ps` where the first thing on the line is something else.) The cake decorator is hoping that the implementation of `kill` on the system doesn't barf when it gets all the other junk following the PID on the `ps` output line.

   [POSIX doesn't say](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/kill.html) what `kill(1)` does with non-PID arguments. It could stop at the first non-numeric argument, it could give errors for each such argument it finds, or it could silently ignore them. If the line found by `ps` happens to contain numbers that are valid PIDs, the command on the cake could end up killing processes you didn't intend it to.

It would be a lot better to use [`pgrep`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pgrep) here, if it's available:

```
# pgrep httpd | xargs kill -9
```

Not only is the command shorter, it does what you actually want, reliably. It doesn't match and then filter out `grep` processes, it only matches on the process name, and it doesn't pass non-PID junk to `kill`.

Systems with `pgrep` often also have the command `pkill`, which wraps up that pipeline into a single command:

```
# pkill httpd
```

You can add `-9` here to forcibly terminate `httpd` processes if you want, but I will leave it off from here on. I've ordered these commands to be increasingly discriminate, so it also makes sense to make them decreasingly *brutal*, if you will.

If your system doesn't have `pgrep` or `pkill`, it may have [`pidof`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/pidof):

```
# kill $(pidof httpd)
```

Yet another method is to use [`killall`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/killall):

```
# killall httpd
```

Beware, the `killall` command may do [something different](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Killall) on non-Linux OSes.

The safest method is to use your OS's normal "stop the web server" command, however. Examples:

```
# service httpd stop
# /etc/init.d/httpd stop
# systemctl stop httpd.service
# launchctl unload /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist
```

Apache includes a "stop Apache nicely" command:

```
# apachectl stop
```

That command will only stop Apache proper, however. The OS-specific commands above may do other cleanup actions as well. If Apache was started by the OS, you should use the OS's own command to stop it, too.

Answer (score -2):

This is a cake-protection command. This command unables a Root to eat the cake, because after this angry users will call the Root, open trouble tickets, etc. :)

Comment: Should 'unable' be 'enable' or 'disable' or something else?