# Wait for process to finish, or user input

Tags: bash

I have a backgrounded process that I would like to wait for (in case it fails or dies), unless I receive user input. Said another way, the user input should interrupt my waiting.

Here's a simplified snippet of my code

```
#!/bin/bash
...

mplayer -noconsolecontrols "$media_url" &
sleep 10 # enough time for it to fail

ps -p $!
if [ $? -ne 0 ]
then
    fallback
else
    read
    kill $!
fi
```

The line that I particularly dislike is `sleep 10`, which is bad because it could be too much time, or not enough time.

Is there a way to `wait $! || read` or the equivalent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `kill -0` to validate that the process is still there and `read` with a timeout of 0 to test for user input.  Something like this?

```
pid=$!
while kill -0 $pid; do
    read -t 0 && exit
    sleep 1
done
```

Comment: This introduces a pretty bad race condition. Suppose the process dies while sleeping, then another process is started with the same pid. You'd be watching a different (random) process!

Answer (score 2):

**Original**

`ps -p` to check the process. `read -t 1` to wait for user input.

```
pid=$!
got_input=142
while ps -p $pid > /dev/null; do
    if read -t 1; then
        got_input=$?
        kill $pid
    fi
done
```

This allows for branching based whether the process died, or was killed due to user input.

---

All credit to gubblebozer. The only reason I'm posting this answer is the claim by moderators that my edits to his post constituted altering his intent.

**Anti Race-Condition**

First off, a race condition involving pids is (very likely) not a concern if you're fairly quick, because they're [reused on a cycle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11323410/linux-pid-recycling).

Even so, I guess anything is possible... Here's some code that handles that possibility, without breaking your head on traps.

```
got_input=142

while true; do
    if read -t 1; then
        got_input=$?
        pkill --ns $$ name > /dev/null
        break
    elif ! pgrep --ns $$ name > /dev/null; then
        break
    fi
done
```

Now, we've accomplished our goal, while (probably) completely eliminating the race condition.

Comment: This introduces a pretty bad race condition. Suppose the process dies while waiting, then another process is started with the same pid, and then the user hits enter. You'd be killing a random process.

Comment: @mvds Interesting. Let me ask. If I say directly `if ps -p $pid; then kill $pid; fi`, is that guaranteed to kill the correct process?

Comment: Still not entirely, you should adopt a different approach. It's better to not "poll" yourself, but to wait for a signal. For more reasons than this race condition alone! See my answer.

Comment: Pids are recycled in a pretty short cycle of 32k, so a collision *will* happen on any system doing intensive work (things like `find ... -exec` will make the pid counter wrap around fast). This is just bad design. If you intend to wait for an event, wait for the event.

Comment: This is pretty great, man.  You're right, the race that @mvds brought up is still there, between `pgrep` and `kill`.  But it's incredibly tiny.  Could use `pkill`?  But that's a minor point, my bet is that what you ended up with will suit your purposes!

Comment: The fact the pid's are reused in a cycle *is the very reason it's a race condition*. Sorry to say but there really is no way out of it, you have to keep a tap on the child process, even before it is started, or something might happen while your script is sleeping (either in a `sleep` or in a `read`). I see no other way than signal handling for it. Maybe you could abuse /proc/pid in some unusual way, like opening /proc/pid/cmdline and then detecting the fd is closed because /proc/pid disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

Any loop with a `sleep` or similar timeout in it, will introduce a race condition. It's better to actively `wait` for the process to die, or, in this case, to trap the signal that's sent when a child dies.

```
#!/bin/bash

set -o monitor
trap stop_process SIGCHLD
stop_process()
{
    echo sigchld received
    exit
}

# the background process: (this simulates a process that exits after 10 seconds)
sleep 10 &

procpid=$!
echo pid of process: $procpid

echo -n hit enter: 
read

# not reached when SIGCHLD is received
echo killing pid $procpid
kill $procpid
```

I'm not 100% sure this eliminates any race condition, but it's a lot closer than a `sleep` loop.

*edit: the shorter, less verbose version*

```
#!/bin/bash

set -o monitor
trap exit SIGCHLD

sleep 5 &

read -p "hit enter: "
kill $!
```

*edit 2: setting the trap before starting the background process prevents another race condition in which the process would die before the trap was installed*

Comment: Maybe the docs are misleading, but `monitor -m` seems superfluous, and `trap exit SIGCHILD` seems wrong. Also, running it doesn't result in the expected behavior. So...

Comment: I don't follow you. Indeed `trap exit SIGCHILD` is wrong because of the superfluous `I` you added. The manpage states that `trap` is followed by a `command`. The manpage also states that `exit` is a `command`. So could you please elaborate on how this "seems wrong"? About `monitor` you may be right.

Comment: You're correct about `SIGCHLD` (was having trouble finding it), but even so this does not work. I spent hours on simple test cases getting nowhere.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand the expected behavior then. I read it as: 1) User input should kill the background process, 2) if the background process dies, don't wait for user input anymore

Comment: Just tested: it indeed doesn't work if you don't call `set -o monitor`, so it doesn't really seem superfluous. Apparently you do have to explicitly "enable job control" to get `SIGCHLD` signals.

Comment: Maybe our systems are different, because here it does **not** work, even with `set -o monitor`. `exit` doesn't get called until after `read` receives input.

Comment: Strange. Tested on a recent and an outdated Debian stable and Mac OS X 10.10 (*GNU bash, version 4.2.37(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)*, *GNU bash, version 4.1.5(1)-release (i486-pc-linux-gnu)* and *GNU bash, version 3.2.53(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin14)*)

Comment: @MichaelPlotke but do you even *want* this to work..?

Comment: I would be thrilled if this worked. Gave up when I found this confirmation of my experience. "When Bash receives a signal for which a trap has been set while waiting for a command to complete, the trap will not be executed until the command completes." - [tldp](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_12_02.html#sect_12_02_02)

Comment: Even then it would only mean you'd need to loop the `read`, so that the trap can be handled between `read` calls.