# How to "adopt" a child process in python

Tags: python, linux, subprocess

How can I get the pid of a child processes that I didn't create an object for? i.e.

```
myProc = Popen(["sleep","30"])
```

vs

```
Popen(["sleep","30"])
```

I've noticed they become zombie processes if I don't poll() or wait() on them after sending a termination signal. At a point in my script I would like to find all child processes that my script is a parent of and send them a signal or poll them. Is this possible in python? Is it possible at all?

Comment: Why not create a global array that you use to hold all the processes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use [`psutil`](http://pythonhosted.org/psutil/) to find the children of your parent Python process. For example:

```
import psutil
import os
import subprocess

subprocess.Popen(['sleep', '30'])

parent_pid = os.getpid()
parent = psutil.Process(parent_pid)

for child in parent.children():
    print(child)    # do something here
```

Prints:

```
psutil.Process(pid=16822, name='sleep')
```

From there you could poll them, kill them etc.

Answer (score 2):

Normally, you don't need to do anything -- the current `subprocess` implementation maintains a global list of active unreferenced `Popen` instances and when a new Popen object is created, this list is enumerate and `.poll()` is called for each process.

Thus if you don't have a reference to the subprocess; it is waited for you automatically (and if you do have a reference then call `.wait()` yourself).

If child processes are created by other means then you could call `os.waitpid()` to collect exit statuses of dead subprocesses on Unix:

```
while True:
    try:
        pid, status = os.waitpid(-1, os.WNOHANG) 
    except ChildProcessError:
        #  No more child processes exist
        break
    else:
        assert pid, "child process is still alive"
```

On POSIX.1-2001 systems, you could call `signal(SIGCHLD, SIG_IGN)` to reap children automatically instead.

If you want to kill all children (send a signal) when a parent dies; you could [use `prctl` `PR_SET_PDEATHSIG` on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19448096/4279). It works if the parent dies for any reason i.e., it works even if the parent is killed by `SIGKILL`.

[`psutil`](https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil) from [@ali_m' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33928086/4279) is a portable solution:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import gc
import subprocess
import time

import psutil


for _ in range(10):
    subprocess.Popen(['sleep', '1'])  # no reference
time.sleep(2)  # wait until they are dead
gc.collect()  # run garbage collection, to populate _active list
subprocess.Popen(['sleep', '1'])  # trigger _cleanup()

for i in range(2):
    for child in psutil.Process().children():  # immediate children
        print(child, child.status())
    if i == 0:
        time.sleep(2)
```

#### Output

```
psutil.Process(pid=31253, name='sleep') sleeping
psutil.Process(pid=31253, name='sleep') zombie
```

Note:

1. `psutil` shows only one zombie process, the rest are reaped in the last `Popen()` call
2. `psutil` provides a protection against [`pid` reuse](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11323410/4279) but it is not 100% reliable in all cases -- check whether it is enough in your case (otherwise, use one the methods above that do not rely on child's `pid`).