# bash move 500 directories at a time to subdirectory from a total of 160,000 directories

Tags: bash, shell, amazon-s3

I needed to move a large s3 bucket to a local file store for a variety of reasons, and the files were stored as 160,000 directories with subdirectories.

As this is just far too many folders to look at with something like a gui FTP interface, I'd like to move the 160,000 root directories into, say, 320 directories - 500 directories in each.

I'm a newbie at bash scripting, and I just wrote this up, but I'm scared I'm going to mangle the whole thing and have to redo the transfer.  I tested with [[ "$i" -ge 3 ]]; and some directories with subdirectories and it looked like it worked okay, but I'm quite nervous.  Do not want to retransfer all this data.

```
i=0;
j=0;

for file in *; do
  if [[ -d "$file" && ! -L "$file" ]];
    then
      ((i++))
      echo "directory $file is being written to assets_$j";
      mv $file ./assets_$j/;
      if [[ "$i" -ge 499 ]];
        then
          ((j++));
          ((i=0));
      fi
  fi;
done
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: you question is not really clear. Can you give an example of what you want with, lets say 10 directories

Comment: Maybe `rsync` can be of utility. If I were you, I would create a file with a list of folders to move, and then I would traverse that file and keep a record in another file of what work has been done.

Comment: You could cp instead of mv.  Then if things go awry, you can just restart it.  In this case, cp shouldn't be much slower (other than the fact that you may want to rm * when you have a good local copy)

Comment: You should probably add a `[[ $file = assets_* ]] && continue` at the top of your loop so you don't try to rename `assets_*` directories that already exist.

Comment: And btw, `if (( i >= 499 ))` is the better bashism for comparing `i` to `499`. If you're going to use a non-POSIX-compliant syntax, might as well pick the more readable, built-to-purpose one. :)

Comment: @dstromberg, ...I'd suggest `ln` instead of `cp`; that way there's no duplication of storage (except for the inodes)..

Comment: @CharlesDuffy when I tested this with when i > 3, it didn't iterate over the new directories...but that's a good defensive piece of code to put in there.

Comment: @Giallo, right; the glob just runs once before the loop is invoked at all, but the concern is what happens if you cancel and restart partway through, or want to incrementally move more files.

Comment: @Giallo, btw, one thing that's more important is changing `mv $file` to `mv "$file"`. Going to have a very bad day with filenames containing spaces or glob characters otherwise. (That's also an issue http://shellcheck.net/ would identify for you automatically).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

- `find` all the directories in the current folder.
- Read a count of the folders.
- Exec `mv` for each chunk

```
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d |
while IFS= readarray -n10 -t files && ((${#files[@]})); do
     dest="./assets_$((j++))/"
     echo mkdir -v -p "$dest"
     echo mv -v "${files[@]}" "$dest";
done
```

Answer (score 3):

On the condition that assets_1, assets_2, etc. do not exist in the working directory yet:

```
dirs=(./*/)
for (( i=0,j=1; i<${#dirs[@]}; i+=500,j++ )); do
    echo mkdir ./assets_$j/ 
    echo mv "${dirs[@]:i:500}" ./assets_$j/
done
```

If you're happy with the output, remove `echo`s.

Comment: I'd suggest `printf '%q ' mv "${dirs[@]:i:50}" ./assets_$j/; echo` -- the way it's done now will misrepresent what is actually run with names with spaces/globs/etc.

Comment: (And maybe add a `-p` to the `mkdir` so it doesn't complain when the directory already exists... well, either that, or loop on incrementing `j` until we get a directory that *doesn't* exist).

Comment: @Charles you're right, but that'd be confusing for OP

Comment: @Charles if the directory already exists, this will make a mess.

Comment: Not if you add a guard to skip files that are itself `assets_*` ones, and the increment loop to find a nonexistent target directory I described above. Which is to say, the mess in question is very preventable.

Comment: (Maybe better to replace `*` with `!(assets_*)`)

Comment: @Charles I'm not saying you're wrong, but these additions would make it too complicated. OP **mustn't** have assets_n dirs in . and everything's gon be fine

Comment: I'm not saying you're wrong either -- the answer has my upvote; just kibitzing, it's what I do. :)

Answer (score 1):

A possible way, but you have no control on the counter, is:

```
find . -type d -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -print0 \
   | xargs -0 -n 500 sh -c 'echo mkdir -v ./assets_$$ && echo mv -v "$@" ./assets_$$' _
```

This gets the counter of `assets` from the PID which only recycles when the wrap-around is reached ([Linux PID recycling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11323410/linux-pid-recycling))

The order which `find`returns is slight different then the glob `*` ([Find command default sorting order](https://serverfault.com/questions/181787/find-command-default-sorting-order))

If you want to have the sort order alphabetically, you can add a simple sort:

```
find . -type d -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -print0 | sort -z \
   | xargs -0 -n 500 sh -c 'echo mkdir -v ./assets_$$ && echo mv -v "$@" ./assets_$$' _
```

**note:** remove the echo if you are pleased with the output