# How to check if a MonoDevelop built application is running in Linux?

Tags: linux, bash, process, mono, redhat

I have a MonoDevelop application built in Red Hat Linux. The below command will start the mono application similar to a windows service

```
mono myMonoApp.exe
```

I need to check in my bash script if the above process is running or not?

For example, I will use the below command to check it for my C++ application that will return the PID of the process if it started already.

```
/usr/bin/pgrep -fx /usr/home/myapplication
```

I tried the pgrep command for the mono application, but its not working

```
/usr/bin/pgrep -fx /usr/home/myMonoApp.exe
```

The **ps -ef | grep myMonoApp** command returns the following:

```
usr11  5380  4845  2 11:52 pts/2    00:00:00 mono myMonoApp.exe
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: What have you tried? What about that example pgrep doesn't work for this case?

Comment: I tried the same command (pgrep) but it didn't work. I also tried this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9117507/linux-unix-command-to-determine-if-process-is-running

Comment: What pgrep command did you try that didn't work? Did you try pidof? How does the program show up in full ps output?

Comment: I have updated the question. I didn't try pidof.

Comment: Thanks Etan Reisner, I  have to use the pgrep command as "/usr/bin/prgrep -fx "mono myMonoApp.exe". Your questions actually provided the solution

Comment: Are you trying to only have a single instance of the app running?

Comment: yes, I am expecting only one instance of the app