# check if command is running in bashrc

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, dropbox

Here is my question. Since there is a problem for my dropbox folder to do automatics sync. I have to add " ~/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd &" in my .bashrc. So whenever I open my terminal, it will automatically start synchronizing. The problem arise when I want to have another tab in my terminal. I am receiving following warning that "Another instance of Dropbox (8664) is running!
". 
Although it does not affect my dropbox, it is quite annoying. 
I searched but unfortunately I could not find the solution on the web. So any help will be appreciated in advance.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Linux/Unix command to determine if process is running?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9117507/linux-unix-command-to-determine-if-process-is-running)

Comment: This does not sound like a command that should be in `.bashrc` but running at boottime instead. Did you try that?

Comment: Use `ps` (with `-C`) to check if the process is running and launch only if not. Alternatively, simply launch and redirect the error messages to `/dev/null` if you don't want to see them.

Comment: @TimZimmermann Thanks, How can I run it at boottime, The point is that I don't have access as root.

Comment: @NoufalIbrahim like "ps -C ~/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd &" ??

Comment: Check the answer that @fredtantini has linked to. It has some code you might be able to repurpose.

Comment: You can create a cronjob that is run on reboot, assuming that you are on a Linux that supports it. Try running `crontab -e` and add the line `@boot /home/user/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd`. Note the absolute path instead of `~`, so you have to substitute your username.

Comment: @TimZimmermann  I receive following: crontab: installing new crontab        
"/tmp/crontab.QcfA8j":1: bad time specifier      
errors in crontab file, can't install.      
Do you want to retry the same edit?

Comment: Okay, then try `@reboot` instead of `@boot`. If that does not work, please tell us on which Linux (Distro) you are working on.

Comment: @TimZimmermann reboot works fine, thanks. Please write your answer in the answer section so i can choose it as the best answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add it to yout .bashrc

```
ps cax | grep dropbox > /dev/null
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
  echo "Process is running."
else
  ~/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd &
  echo "Process is not running."
fi
```

Comment: This will incorrectly mark the process as already running if another user on the system is running it.  Also, the `grep` will match process names which contain `dropbox` as a substring, not just exact matches (though that could be fixed with a tighter regex and/or additional options).

Comment: And of course, anything that looks like `pipeline; if [ $0 -eq 0 ]; then` is more idiomatically written `if pipeline; then`

Answer (score 1):

Add a guard to your `.bashrc` to only run it if it isn't running already.

```
pidof -c dropboxd || ./~dropbox-dist/dropboxd &
```

(This is assuming you have `pidof` but that should be trivially true on most modern Linux distros.)

Comment: You might want to specify the full path in the argument to `pidof` if there could be multiple users running the same command. There unfortunately doesn't seem to be an option to only examine processes of your own; but most likely only you would run a binary from your home directory tree.

Answer (score 0):

Building from @tripleee's answer, the following works with the [official Dropbox Python control script](http://www.dropboxwiki.com/tips-and-tricks/using-the-official-dropbox-command-line-interface-cli) (eg for headless Digital Ocean boxes) and doesn't output the pid on screen:

```
pidof -c dropbox > /dev/null || ~/bin/dropbox.py start # start dropbox
```

It assumes you have [dropbox.py](http://www.dropboxwiki.com/tips-and-tricks/using-the-official-dropbox-command-line-interface-cli) stored in ~/bin and marked executable.

Comment: It's not entirely clear where you're getting the python script from - is [this](https://www.dropbox.com/download?dl=packages/dropbox.py) the one you mean?

Comment: @SimonMᶜKenzie yes the offical dropbox.py, it is needed for non-graphical Linux systems. I have now edited to clarify.