# Testing a Current Process

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I'm creating a program that plays a video when a GPIO button is pressed and once the selected video ends and closes I want to play a filler video while no button is pressed. To do this, I was wondering how one would check if a certain program is running programmatically?

```
import RPi.GPIO as gpio
import time, sys, os

gpio.setmode(gpio.BCM)
gpio.setup(23, gpio.IN)
gpio.setup(25, gpio.IN)

os.system('pkill omxplayer')
os.system('omxplayer -b Shopping.mp4 &')

while True:
    if gpio.input(23):
        os.system('pkill omxplayer')
        os.system('omxplayer -b Shopping.mp4 &')

    if gpio.input(25):
        os.system('pkill omxplayer')
        os.system('omxplayer -b Dodgeball.mp4 &')

    # if omxplayer is not running, then run the filler video
```

Comment: [Linux/Unix command to determine if process is running?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9117507/846892)

Comment: Yes, I already know about `ps` but how do I actually check in python?

Comment: Run it using [`subprocess.call`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call) and check the return code, if it's 0 then process is running.

Comment: Can I do the same with `os.system` or not?

Comment: Of course, but re-read `os.system` in documentation which recommends using `subprocess`.