# apache tomcat not starting while service tomcat start

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat6, catalina

I am using RHEL 7 os with this i am using apache tomcat6. while try to start it using this command i am getting this message as:

Starting tomcat6: /etc/init.d/tomcat6: line 70: checkpid: command not found

and at line number 70 the code is as:

```
if checkpid $kpid 2>&1; then
            echo "process allready running"
            return -1
        else
            echo "lock file found but no process running for pid $kpid, continuing"
        fi
```

after this execute the command i got process id for tomcat by this command:

```
[root@localhost ~]# ps -ef | grep tomcat
root     14074 13882  0 01:50 pts/1    00:00:00 grep --color=auto tomcat
```

but my war file is not deployed and also localhost:8080 is not working.

Comment: please add the catalina log

Comment: see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9118509/3224238) for another way to check if the process is running

Comment: "/etc/init.d/tomcat6: line 70: checkpid: command not found" this sounds like a bug in the init script. The init script comes from the vendor--it's not part of tomcat itself--so if you didn't modify it, you should complain to the vendor.

Comment: actually its a modified script.

it works regular in RHEL 5 but not in RHEL 7.

and one more thing i would like to mention is this script uses function file and its a function name(checkpid) but some how it is not able to import in main script file.

it is working fine with RHEL 5.