# How to monitor remote java process

Tags: java, linux

I am starting a java program on a remote machine using `ssh` to log into the machine and then running the command. The ssh session is created using the `JCraft` java library. The process is starting a REST server, and is put into the background with '&'. The program is started as follows:

```
java -cp $ATFIMAGE/atf.jar com.atf.agent.jobs.SlaveRunner dub-001948-VM01 8888 8889  > /home/john/testHome/SlaveRunner_stdout.log 2> /home/john/testHome/SlaveRunner_stderr.log  &
```

The approach I am using at the moment is to scp the stderr file from the remote server and check if it's empty. If the file is empty, then I can say that it started correctly. This works but it's not that robust:

```
  session.command(javaCmd);
  manager.copyArtefactFromTarget(remoteHost, remoteStdErrFile, localFileSystem);
```

If there is any delay starting the java process, the stderr can be empty, and then populated after I collect it from the server.

Using the unix exit code is not an option, as the process is put into the background. You only get the code when the process exits, but in this case the process didn't even start.

Just wondering if there is anyway to monitor the process, and whether it started correctly.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1908610/how-to-get-pid-of-background-process

Comment: If  all you're concerned about is 'did it start correctly' then when don't you try to make a request to the server?

Comment: I aim doing a request to the server later in the program, and have implemented a retry mechanism there. That will never succeed though since the REST server didn't even start. It could have failed for many different reasons. Wrong java version, java not on classpath etc. The reason I would like to get feedback on whether it started or not is so that I can notify the user of the problem (java not on classpath for example), and exit the application. Manual intervention is required, so it is up to the user to fix it, and re-run the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the process id of your background task via

`echo $!`

(see [How to get PID of background process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1908610/how-to-get-pid-of-background-process))

Then you can use that pid to poll if the process is still alive (see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/14880926/1015327). If the process died you can react accordingly; and you can stop polling once the REST service becomes functional. You can also kill the process if it fails to activate the REST service within a certain timespan.

However, to me it seems that your protocol may be a little complicated and error-prone. Have you considered other approaches for running a (Java-)server?

Comment: That would probably work, but I think you are right - I think it would also be error prone. I don't have any other ideas for starting the server.