# Determine if a tar process sent with sendkeys has terminated

Tags: linux, vbscript, tar

I'm new here. We have a vbs script for a backup on our server.

we send Linux commands with sendkeys.
the specific command is:

```
objWshShell.SendKeys "tar -cvpzf /mnt/system/system.tar.gz --one-file-system /"
```

working fine.

i want to terminate the vbs script, when the tar process on server has terminated.

thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9117507/linux-unix-command-to-determine-if-process-is-running

Comment: well, i think i found a solution:
1. i entered a "; exit" after the tar command to logout.
2. i modified securecrt, our ssh client to close if logged out
3 i created a vbscript loop determinating if securecrt is active,
if not (the case when logged out) i open a dialog saying that backup was successfully. <OK>
that's it
now i have not to calculate a wscript.sleep pause, which could be too short or which would be too long ..

cheers